# how to pass null value to a date type parameter in a snowflake procedure via c# code

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using a c# .net code to update values in snowflake tables.i have created procedure for that in snowflake.but the issue is when i pass a null value to a snowflake procedure which has date type parameter it shows error.

So what I'm trying to do is pass a default date like '0001-01-01' which I will pass if the date is null and I will modify the snowflake procedure if its '0001-01-01' then null value will be passed to that table.

What I tried:

```
cmd.CommandText = "call SP_ADDORUPDATES('" + Nugget.NuggetID + "','" + Nugget.BeginDate == null ? "0001-01-01" : DateTime.ParseExact(Nugget.BeginDate, "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "')";
```

This to shows error that. String reference, not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s

Kindly help me, is there a way to pass null value to a snowflake procedure date parameter while calling the procedure. Or how to pass this default value like above to the procedure.

```
the code which i tried before that is passing null to the value is:
cmd.CommandText = "call SP_ADDORUPDATES('" + Nugget.NuggetID + "','" + (Nugget.BeginDate == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : DateTime.ParseExact(Nugget.BeginDate, "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) + "')";
```

Which shows error:
`Date '' is not recognized.`

Comment: I'd be surprised if the Snowflake ODBC driver doesn't support parameters. Try `call SP_ADDORUPDATES(?, ?)` and then use `.Parameters.Add` to add the values as typed values, rather than interpolating strings. This takes care of any formatting and escaping issues to boot.

Comment: I tried it but it is showing that the feature is not supported if u have can u please share the syntax. For calling the procedure..using parameters.will be much help full..pal

Comment: @stageblake "I tried it but it is showing that the feature is not supported if u have can u please share the syntax" - please show us your attempts

Comment: Hi - what language is the Snowflake SP written in?